# can't format cells that have vlookup values

Tags: vlookup, google-spreadsheets

I have a secondary tab that is pulling live data using ImportJSON(). When I grab data from that into primary tab with a vlookup, I'm unable to then format the cell. If I open format > number menu, the format I chose has been set, but the data does not display as %.

How can I get formatting to work?

Answer (score 0):

You need the TEXT() Function along with the Vlookup to display the result in % Format.

I have had the same issues while I was using the Vlookup Function and Importjson.gs

Below is a sample Formula, will help you.

```
=TEXT(VLOOKUP(A8,data,8,FALSE),"0.0%")
```

**NB:** For more details on this issue you can also refer this link.

Now let me clear one crucial issue. The above written Formula will convert the looked up value into percentage, simply multiply it by 100. Like 1 will 100%, and Excel therefore mean it. So be careful.

If your simple intention is display the % sign along with the Number then use this,

```
=TEXT(VLOOKUP(A8,Data,8,FALSE),"0.0")&"%"
```

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?hl=en